# Get info from a long list of items

Tags: android, list, object

So I have this `Object`:

```
InstagramUserSummary(super=test, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=test, is_favorite=false, is_private=true, username=test, pk=test, profile_pic_url=test, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=test)
```

How can I get the username from this object? Can I turn it into a list?

EDIT:

```
 List List = result2.getUsers();
 Object list1 = List.get(1); <--- this is the list I showed above!
 Log.d("list", String.valueOf(list1)); <--- this is how I show it/display it.
```

EDIT:

What should I change Object to.... (Is that how you fix this)

EDIT: How can a parse this list?

EDIT:

I have this object that when `String.valueOf(object))`, it returns:

```
InstagramUserSummary(super=test, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=test, is_favorite=false, is_private=true, username=test, pk=121, profile_pic_url=test, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=test)
```

How can I turn this object into a list or hashmap of (so I can get what the values equal):

```
[super=test, is_verified=false, profile_pic_id=test, is_favorite=false, is_private=true, username=test, pk=121, profile_pic_url=test, has_anonymous_profile_picture=false, full_name=test]
```

Comment: Assuming `getUsers()` actually returns a `List` of `InstagramUserSummary`, change to `List<InstagramUserSummary> list = result2.getUsers();`, `InstagramUserSummary user = list.get(1);`, `String username = user.getUsername();`.